# Mayor valor en un Array introducido js

Tags: javascript, array

Necesito ayuda con este ejercicio, de alguna manera simple, ya que no tengo un nivel experto...
Realizar un programa en el cual se debera ingresar 5 numeros en un vector, luego debera mostrar cual es el mayor de ellos.

```
var arreglo=[];
var mayor=0;
for(i=0;i<arreglo.length;i++){
  var number=prompt('Ingrese un numero');
  vector.push(parseInt(number));
}
alert();
```

Solo llegue a hacer esto, hay partes como el alert y la condicion para buscar el mayor valor que estan sin completar...Necesito que al ingresar en un array los valores, se recorra el array y se muestre el numero mayor, Gracias!

Comment: Recibiste una muy buena respuesta, solo para reforzar: `Realizar un programa en el cual se deberá ingresar 5 números en un vector` en lo que te solicitan dice la cantidad total de valores a ingresar, así que hasta ese valor ibas a recorrer el `for` para pedir los números

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Te coloco primero el ejemplo y después te lo explico

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>JS Bin</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="res"></div>
    <script>
        let arreglo = []
        
        for(let i = 1; i<=5; i++) {
          let numero = prompt("Teclea un número")
          arreglo.push(numero)
        }
        document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = Math.max(...arreglo)
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**ACLARACIONES**

- Declaro una variable `arreglo` como arreglo vacío por fuera del for para usarlo después
- Como necesito pedir 5 números cualquiera entonces hago uso de `prompt()` asignado a una variable para almacenar cada número que teclea el usuario
- Por dentro del `for` con ayuda del método `push` lleno el array `arreglo`
- Por medio de `getElementById()` obtengo un `div` que es donde imprimiré el número mayor
- Al usar el método `Math.max()` obtengo el mayor de un grupo de números
- Hacemos uso del `spread operator` de este modo `...nombreArreglo` para operar que pueden llegar múltiples argumentos al método `max()` aunque también se podría con `apply()`