# obtener el numero mayor de un arreglo

Tags: javascript

Estoy obteniendo números máximo 5 mediante un prompt, quiero que se acumulen en un array a medida que se van escribiendo y que al final me indique cual es el numero mayor del array, como se podría hacer esta ultima parte he tratado con math.max(number) pero no funciona.

Gracias por la ayuda

```js
var number = [];
var input_number = "";

for(i=1; i<=5; i++){
  if(input_number !== 0){
    input_number = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese un número"));
    number.push(input_number);
    console.log(number);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

La sintaxis de `Math.max` es que su argumento deber ser una lista de números pero `number` es un Array. Una forma de convertir una Array en una lista es mediante `apply` pero si el interprete objetivo de JavaScript, que podría ser una navegador, soporta ECMAScript recientes podrías usar el operador `spread`

Usando `apply`

```js
var number = [];
var input_number = "";

for(i=1; i<=5; i++){
  if(input_number !== 0){
    input_number = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese un número"));
    number.push(input_number);
  }
}

console.log(Math.max.apply(null,number));
```

Usando el operador `spread`

```js
var number = [];
var input_number = "";

for(i=1; i<=5; i++){
  if(input_number !== 0){
    input_number = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese un número"));
    number.push(input_number);
  }
}

console.log(Math.max(...number));
```

Otra forma que no requiere el uso de `Math.max` es usar el operador ternario, el cual podría ser recomendable en caso de que no requieras conservar todos los valores ingresados.

```js
var input_number = "";
var mayor = 0;

for(i=1; i<=5; i++){
  if(input_number !== 0){
    input_number = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese un número"));
    mayor = (mayor > input_number) ? mayor: input_number;
    
  }
}

console.log(mayor);
```

Referencias

- https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Math/max
- https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Conditional_Operator

Relacionado

- [Mayor valor en un Array introducido js](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/238972/65)

Answer (score 2):

Podrías utilizar el operador [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Spread_operator) (...):

```
var number = [];
var input_number = "";

for(i=1; i<=5; i++){
  if(input_number !== 0){
    input_number = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese un número"));
    number.push(input_number);
    console.log(number);
  }
}

function mayor(...arr) { 
   alert(Math.max(...arr)) 
} 

mayor(...number);
```

Comment: De hecho ni siquiera necesitas declararlo dentro de una función, puede quedar así: `console.log(Math.max(...number))`

Comment: Así mismo, se puede utilizar directamente

Comment: Justamente. Antes se hacía con Max.math.apply(null, [1,2,3...6])